To Array Working Differ in Eloquent and Db Facade why?

$res = User::select(Db::raw('internal_code,request_key'))->whereInternalCode('TXN')->limit(2)->get()->toArray();

$res = array:2 [
  0 => array:2 [
    "internal_code" => "172.16.213.6"
    "request_key" => "h0069b8a4b16-8326-4f3c-8897-9244991d4a49-4M0ToOmtYTAX"
  ]
  1 => array:2 [
    "internal_code" => "172.16.213.6"
    "request_key" => "h0069b8a4fb3-dc4d-4238-9996-bc4ec8fe0a5d-a6WAEO4H2xkr"
  ]
]

$res2 = DB::connection($destinationDb.'__read')
            ->table("$destinationTable as d")
            ->leftJoin("$soruceDb.$soruceTable as s", "d.".strtolower($configRule['rule']['destination_lookup_key']), '=', "s.".strtolower($configRule['rule']['source_lookup_key']))
            ->select(Db::raw(implode(',',$prefixedSourColumns)))
            ->limit(2)
            ->get()->toArray();
$res2 = array:2 [
  0 => {#1734
    +"status": "SUCCESS"
    +"operator_id": "BR000AL6A8TF,"
  }
  1 => {#1735
    +"status": "SUCCESS"
    +"operator_id": "BR000AL6AFEM,"
  }
]

There is difference in both result while using same method get()->toArray()
In First i am getting row as nested arrays
While in Second i am getting row as nested Object
Why and how can i get nested array as well in second query
I want to know the reason, as what could be solution to get row as nested array as well in second query`

simply because the first one is casted to instances of User::class that implements Illuminate\Contracts\Support\Arrayable and so has a defined toJson() and toArray() methods in Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model::class and  second one is raw data casted to stdClass::class (the generic php class)
When you call toArray() on a collection it checks if the entry is arrayable
public function toArray()
{
    return $this->map(fn ($value) => $value instanceof Arrayable ? $value->toArray() : $value)->all();
}

If not it will return the map of the value itself using Illuminate\Support\Arr::map() which uses the php method array_map() to convert it to array.
public static function map(array $array, callable $callback)
{
    $keys = array_keys($array);

    try {
        $items = array_map($callback, $array, $keys);
    } catch (ArgumentCountError) {
        $items = array_map($callback, $array);
    }

    return array_combine($keys, $items);
}

In the end, if you want the same result, uses raw DB calls for both or use Model class for both.
